# What are the graphical and thematic trend cycles in web design?

Tags: design

I think web design is not different than any other technology aesthetic, and there are trends that form from successful standouts being copied, but through a slight overcompensation, which then builds upon the trend.  For instance bell bottom jeans--first a designer had a slightly wide cut, which proved original, and then the next season 5 other designers did the same but wider.  And so on, until after a couple years, bell bottoms were super wide and a designer came up with a peg leg and that "reset" the trend.  You can see this in other forms of art/technology/culture --> ford explorer, brings the jeep cherokee, brings the cadillac and then the hummer to be reset by the mini or prius.

OK. . . so the question I have, is how might these sort of trend cycles manifest in web design?

Comment: Great new question +1

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question. I don't know if anyone has really looked at it from a historical perspective. There are plenty of good sites doing yearly trend rundowns (eg [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/04/web-design-trends-2010/), [Mashable](http://mashable.com/2010/09/28/web-logo-design-trends/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter), [Web Design Ledger](http://webdesignledger.com/tips/web-design-trends-for-2010), [Noupe](http://www.noupe.com/), and others.

It would be great to see a historical perspective on this.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. . . I was a bit hesitant to put it up, wanting not to go against the community guidelines here.  But it looks like it's been voted up three times, although only one answers. . . yours :-/

Comment: and great links in your answer. +1